# Gnome 3.2 theme does not change

Tags: gnome, themes

I am having trouble changing my gnome 3.2 themes. After I download and extract themes, I try to use them using gnome tweak tool. Only the title bar is affected and nothing else(icons, borders, etc) changes. I am a complete newbie to ubuntu and I am currently using ubuntu 11.10. Please help!

Comment: FYI - I found that I often had to log out and back in to see a theme take full effect. I don't know why, maybe it was a configuration problem.

Comment: Just reloading gnome shell (ALT+F2, "r") is sufficient, you don't need to log out.

Answer (score 2):

To completely change **everything** you don't just need a gnome-shell theme. A gnome-shell theme is **only** for the title bar and the activities overlay. You also need a GTK+ theme (for the windows), a window theme (for the borders & window buttons) and a new icon theme.

Some packages obtainable from custom PPAs contain all of these, but most of the time you will have to pick them yourself. You can set each of these in the gnome-tweak-tool in the same tab where you changed your shell theme.

Here are some neat ppas that I use:

Satays ppa: https://launchpad.net/~satyajit-happy/+archive/themes ([deviantART](http://satya164.deviantart.com/))

The one and only best icon-theme is Faenza: https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox

Webupd8 also maintains a nice theme ppa: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/themes/+packages ([Announcement](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/announcing-webupd8-themes-ppa.html))