# Gnome Tweak Tool Help!

Tags: gnome, themes

I am trying to change a theme in Gnome3. I have the 3.10.4 version. I installed tweak tool and userShellExtension, but once i am installing the a random theme nothing but the `Shell theme` dropdown options changes....
`Window`,`gtk+`,`icons`,`cursor` dropdown options are remaining the same!

I really cant find anything to help myself and i really am asking for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set individual themes for each of these. You can set a window theme, an icon theme, and a cursor theme individually.

Comment: @Sarriman You may need to log out and log back in and also make sure the permissions are set correctly and you do have to extract the theme if it is in the form of a tar or zip file. See comment here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/86347/gnome-3-2-theme-does-not-change Additionally, it needs to be a gtk-3.0 compatible theme. Gtk-2.0 themes are not compatible and the icon and cursor themes need to go in an .icons directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since i didn't find anywhere the following i am posting it here!

The themes folder was located into the `/usr/share/` directory and thats where the themes need to be extracted!